# How can I efficiently create a new column using multiple DFs and columns? Pandas, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a new column using 2 dataframes, and 3 columns. The operation I am performing is getting a float and string from DF's A and B. I am using the string from DF A to get a corresponding float value from DF B, and dividing both floats to create a new column in DF A.

Currently I created a Dictionary from DF B, with the string as the key and the float as the index. I find the string from DF A, find the corresponding float in the dictionary, and divide them.

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to use different dataframes and columns to calculate a new value.

Sorry if this is a little confusing -- I appreciate the help!

DF A:

Zip Code, Region, Population

14092, Boca, 34513.0

DF B:

Region, Population

Boca, 142019.0

I want to get the Region from DF A, use it to find population in DF B, and then divide population in DF A by population in DF B.

DF A:

Zip Code, Region, Population, PercentOfRegion

14092, Boca, 34513.0, 0.24

Comment: please share an example of your data with the expected output.

Comment: hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: Is dfa["Population"] = dfa["Region"].map(dictionaryyoucreated) really that bad?